# What is the difference between these two calls / ways to read String from Excel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, excel-interop

What is the difference between these two different ways to read a string from an Excel speadsheet while working with the Excel Interop in C#?

```
        String node1 = ((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[row, "A"]).Value2.ToString();
        String node1 = ws.Cells[row, "A"].ToString();
```

Is one better, more correct/through than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though it has to do with [Date and Currency data types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182812).

> The Value2 property, which you can use for the Range object, is
>   almost identical to the Value property except that the Value2 property
>   does not use the Currency and Date data types. Depending on how a cell
>   is formatted (for example, with date, currency, or other formats), the
>   two properties may return different values for the same cell.